# Rails, ember-cli-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ember-cli

I tried to deploy a `Rails & Ember-cli` application to a `VPS` by `Capistrano`. I have integrated `Ember-cli` into `Rails` by using `ember-cli-rails` gem. The problem happens when `Capistrano` wants to do `assets:precompile`. Throwing an error like `EmberCLI Rails requires your Ember app to have an addon.` In this case, I am able to run `assets:precompile` on my local machine and on the server in the `released` directory without any problem. On server I have installed `Nodejs and NPM.

**deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.1.0'
set :application, 'APPLICATION NAME'
set :repo_url, 'GIT ADDRESS'
set :deploy_to, 'SERVER SIDE ADDRESS'
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
namespace :deploy do
 desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
  on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do      
 end
end
 after :publishing, 'deploy:restart'
 after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
 after :restart, :clear_cache do
on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
  end
end
end
```

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.2.0'
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
```

**Related Gems**

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'capistrano-rvm', github: "capistrano/rvm"
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this problem by adding some tasks to my `deploy.rb` file.

Comment: will you please tell me what rake task you have written?

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to answer you sooner than now, I posted my rake tasks as a second answer , I just put them in `deploy.rb` in `rails` side, I hope it helps, even though it is been a long time you asked it

Answer (score 0):

```
desc "Build Ember addon"
  task :build_ember_addon do
   on roles(:app) do
  execute "cd #{release_path}/frontend  && /home/$USER/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/bin/npm install --save-dev ember-cli-rails-addon@0.0.11"
end
end

desc "Intall npm"
 task :npm_install do
  on roles(:app) do
  execute "cd #{release_path}/frontend && /home/$USER/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/bin/npm install"
end
end

desc "bower install"
 task :bower_install do
  on roles(:app) do
  execute "cd #{release_path}/frontend && /home/$USER/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/bin/bower install --config.interactive=false"
end
end

before 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:build_ember_addon'
before 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:npm_install'
before 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:bower_install'
```